# How can I detect the results of Conditional Formating using VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, conditional-formatting, vba

I have an excel file that has conditional formating set up to put a check or an x in a cell. How can I create an if statement that will detect which is in there without using the original conditioning formulas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this homemade function to check if condition is filled: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CFColors.htm