# How to capture Conditional formatting highlights in vba code

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have multiple  conditions in the workbook, few of them are bit complicated, so if any condition is not satisfied I have to throw a message , as I cannot give the conditions in vba for all , I gave it in conditional formatting.

So I try to capture the highlights in VBA code like

```
If Sheets("ABC").range("A3:D8"). Displayformat.font.color = 255 then 
    Msgbox " invalid"
Endif
```

Now I'm trying to capture the cells which has  yellow highlightings in the range, but I'm not successful in that. I have tried color index , RGB etc to capture but it's not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect the results of Conditional Formating using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049023/how-can-i-detect-the-results-of-conditional-formating-using-vba)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56713741/function-to-return-interior-colour-of-conditional-formatted-cell/56723004#56723004